# Keras Custom Layer Aware of Position in Network

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, custom-layer

I'm writing a custom Layer in TF/Keras (`tf.keras.layers.Layer`) for a CNN, and I need each layer to know its own depth in the model.

Is there any way I can do this, without explicitly passing it as an argument?

Comment: Could you please share some insights?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed I essentially want to initialize the weights of a CNN as a function of the depth of the layer in the network. Similar to how Glorot initializes as a function of fan-in/fan-out, I want to use depth instead.